# Perforce cannot retrieve data

Tags: linux

> [build@RHEL6 ~]$ /usr/bin/p4 -p perforce.ges.example.com:1666 workspace

**OUTPUT**  *User build doesn't exist.*

> [build@RHEL6 ~]$ /usr/bin/p4 -p perforce.ges.example.com:1666 workspaces

**OUTPUT**  *User build doesn't exist.*

The perforce server is pingable and folowing are my perforce server details:

> [build@RHEL6 ~]$ /usr/bin/p4 -p perforce.ges.example.com:1666 info

User name: build
Client name: RHEL6
Client host: RHEL6.3-64-BuildMac
Client unknown.
Current directory: /home/build
Why is this happening that i cannot run the perforce commands from my RHEL 6.3 Machine

Comment: Are you sure you want to be posting all that information about your company's internal perforce server here? I don't know how strict symantec is about this sort of thing, but some companies frown upon posting information about intranet servers publicly. I'd recommend contacting internal support, or asking one of your coworkers how to use your p4 server properly - or at least blanking out all the server addresses and paths there. (Of course, if you know your employer is fine with this sort of thing, then by all means go ahead and ask here)

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the user `build` (which you are logged in as in Linux) hasn't been created on the perforce server. The perforce server user database and the Linux user database are independent; you may need to ask your perforce administrator what perforce user you should be using. You can then use the `-u username` flag to specify the right perforce user, rather than using the default derived from the Linux username.